# Enum integer value

Tags: vb.net

I have an Enum like this:

```
    Public Enum Categories
    Category1 = 1
    Category2 = 2
    Category3 = 3
    Category4 = 4
    Category5 = 5
    Category6 = 6
    Category7 = 7
    Category999 = 999
End Enum
```

When I try to get the integer value of Category999 I get 8, and not 999. How can I get the correct integer value?

```
cat = DirectCast(999, Categories)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the integer value - you should be using a variable of the enum type.

Comment: `Dim intValue As Integer = Categories.Category999` would do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the "integer value of Category999" you do:

```
Dim intValue As integer = DirectCast(Categories.Category999, integer)
```